# Purge lines in a CSV file that are older than a certain date

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file with the following column headers:  DateSent, Name, Email.  I file is written to on a daily basis and continues to grow.  I would like to read the file into PowerShell and delete all rows with a date that are older than 120 days.  The DateSent format is MM/dd/yyyy.  I have tried:

> $PurgeDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-120).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')

> Import-Csv $Logfile | where {$_.DateSent -lt $PurgeDate} | export-csv $Logfile

But it wipes the entire file clean.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The date format `MM/dd/yyyy` is *not alphabetically sortable* - January 1st 2022 would come before December 31st 2021 for example.

Instead, use a real `[datetime]` value for the threshold, and then *parse* the input value - this way you'll be comparing two `[datetime]` values, and PowerShell will automatically be able to compare and sort those correctly:

```
$PurgeDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-120)

Import-Csv $Logfile | where {[datetime]::ParseExact($_.DateSent, 'MM/dd/yyyy', $null) -lt $PurgeDate} | export-csv $Logfile
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I entered the code but it is still purging the entire file.

Comment: @talway And you're absolutely certain that it contains rows with dates older than 120 days?

Comment: Yes, it goes back to 09/01/2021.  I changed the get-date.adddays to (-30) just to test.  Thinking that maybe the datetime format in the CSV file was not matching up correctly, I also tried some variations of the MM/dd/yyyy format but that too did not produce the correct results.